# Symfony2.5 + FOSUserBundle check path apparently not found

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I started a new Symfony app on which I use the FOSUserBundle.
I installed it, loaded the bundle and configured it.
Here's my `configuration.yml`:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Myapp\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

and my `security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Now, when I go to `localhost/myapp/web/app_dev.php/login`, I get the following Error 500 after I try to login (I have no problem accessing the login form, this comes after I submit):

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration

It seems to me that `form_login` is configured in my security firewall configuration... what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am thinking that you didn't import FOSUserBundle's routing file. Did you?

In case didn't this is how you do it:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files

Other than that, what is the purpose of that `default` firewall? It could be intercepting the security component when it tries to "find the correct firewall to use".

Comment: I did import the routing file. But you were right about the default firewall, removing it solved the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: I think this link should be used instead of the broken one in your answer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files

Comment: Thanks :) I replaced my URL with yours ;)