# login check for FOSUSER

Tags: symfony

I keep getting this error: `You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.`

I tried this
[Symfony2.5 + FOSUserBundle check path apparently not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498442/symfony2-5-fosuserbundle-check-path-apparently-not-found)

I tried ths
[You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874725/you-must-configure-the-check-path-to-be-handled-by-the-firewall-using-form-login)

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: /login_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /
        logout:       true
```

in routing

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

I'm at lost what to do at all.

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: What does the route for fos_user_security_check resolve to? E.g. the output from ./app/console router:debug | grep fos_user - I think by default it is login-check, not login_check (could be wrong though)

Comment: Show you config of FOSUser(config.yml file)

Comment: @Roberto, I updated. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the check path and the login path from your firewall it's not important !

**Edit :** 
Make your routing.yml in  Acme\MyBundle\Resources\config with the code bellow :

```
    fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register  
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix: /
fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

And add an import to your app/config/routing.yml :

```
    _user_bundle:
  resource: "@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Comment: unfortunately, the same thing

Comment: Your directory folder for routing.yml ?

Comment: Just app/config/routing, no?

Comment: hmm but  i dont have routing in there